# The number of sets of size k, containing distinct numbers $\leq m$, which sum to $n$

Tags: number-theory

$$Y(n,m,k) = \left|\{s \mid s \in \mathcal P (\{1,2,3...m\}),Sum(s) =n, |s| = k  \}\right|$$

Is what I'm going for. Does anyone know if this function has a name? Or if there's an algebraic formula for calculating it?

Comment: This is related to the [Subset Sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) problem... I highly doubt that there is an easy algebraic formula to do what you want.

Comment: @apnorton I can already say, that if $k>\lfloor \sqrt{2n}\rfloor \lor \lfloor \sqrt{2n}\rfloor>m \text {(Assuming, we create the least positive values less than m)}$, then there can't be any, because $T_k >n$ at that point, where T_k is the least sum of k distinct positive integers ( aka triangular number k).